# Why do we convert string to charArray when we do operations on a string?

Tags: java, string, algorithm

When I do algorithm exercises, I found many people like to transfer a string to charArray before do operations?

I don't understand why do we bother do that? I mean, I can use `string.charAt()`, why use `string.toCharArray()` and then `charArray[i]`? It's the same and even `charArray` use O(n) memory.

Can anyone explain that to me?

Comment: Why don't you ask the peoples who have written that code? And this question might also depend on the operations you're talking about.

Comment: there are several reasons: `String` is immutable thus, if you want to manipulate the string it's always faster to generate the charArray first. And the access of an array-element is way faster than `charAt`. Would expand this to an answer, but since @SotiriosDelimanolis closed the question for no reason...

Comment: @Paul The answers in the duplicated question already contain exactly that information. That's what 'duplicate' means.

Comment: @Paul: I don't usually do Java, but `StringBuffer` is a mutable string, and still has `indexOf()` and all the usual `String` stuff.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html.  So `String` being immutable isn't sufficient explanation.  StringBuffer was in JDK1.0, so it's not new.  There must be some other reason it doesn't get used.  I'd guess probably working with an array of `char` is more straightforward.

Comment: @PeterCordes `StringBuffer` and `String` are two completely different things. `String` **is** immutable, `StringBuffer` isn't since it's purpose is to manipulate Strings. But in general it's way faster to manipulate an array than calling `charAt`. Might be more straightforward aswell, but it's rather a matter of personal coding-style than anything else.

Comment: @Paul: I meant, why do people use a char array instead of a `StringBuffer`.  They're closely related, and yes, and are the obvious two choices for manipulating a `String`.  I agree with your guess that it's probably more about coding style and not wanting to litter your code with `setCharAt(i)` / `charAt(i)`, since Java doesn't overload operators to allow indexing a string with array syntax.  Is an array really faster after a decent JIT-compiler is done with the `charAt()` calls?

Comment: @PeterCordes take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several reasons why people prefer `char[]` over `String` and `StringBuffer`:

- `String` is immutable. This means, if you want to manipulate a `String` without using any utilityclass you'll wind up copying the `String` pretty often, which results in extremely inefficient code.
- accessing Characters in a `char[]` is way faster than using `charAt` (though it takes some time to convert a `String` to a `char[]`, which should be considered aswell, when optimizing):

  ```
  class Test{
      public static void main(String[] args){
          String s = "a";
          char[] c = new char[]{'a'};
          StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("a");

          char x;

          long time = System.nanoTime();
          for(int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++)
              x = s.charAt(0);
          time = System.nanoTime() - time;

          System.out.println("string: " + time);

          time = System.nanoTime();
          for(int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++)
              x = c[0];
          time = System.nanoTime() - time;

          System.out.println("[]: " + time);

          time = System.nanoTime();
          for(int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++)
              x = buffer.charAt(0);
          time = System.nanoTime() - time;

          System.out.println("buffer: " + time);
      }
  }
  ```

  Running this simple class results in the following output (on my machine, using javaSE 1.8.0 build b132):

  > string: 37895
  >   []: 18948
  >   buffer: 85659

  So obviously access via `char[]` is way faster than using a `String` or `StringBuilder`.
- using an Object to manipulate single characters will result in a code stuffed with `charAt()` and `setCharAt()`, which might be considered ugly code.
- Security: `String` is rather insecure, if the code handles sensitive data, since the immutable `String` will be stored in memory. This means that the `String` containing sensitive data will be accessible until the GC removes it from the memory. `char[]` on the other hand can be simply overwritten at any time and thus remove the sensitive data from memory.

Comment: Java microbenchmarks are pretty meaningless.  This runs too quickly for the JIT compiler to do its job.  Even cranking the counts way up doesn't help StringBuffer, though, so maybe it's a bad class that doesn't optimize away.  Or maybe the JIT-compiler can see that the loops do nothing for the `String` and array cases, but not StringBuffer.  IDK, but it's not much of a test.  Still, it's a data point that indicates that StringBuffer might be slower.